# Strange output from fread when called from knitr

Tags: r, data.table, knitr

I'm using the recently introduced `fread` function from `data.table` to read data files. 
When I wrap my code into a knitr (Rmd) document, I noticed some strange output, namely lines like:

```
## 
0%
```

even though the `verbose` option of `fread` was set to FALSE. I've used `sink` to hide this output, but I'd like to report the exact problem to the package author(s). Here's a minimal example,

````
library(knitr)

test = "```{r}
require(data.table) 
fread('1 2 3\n')
```"
knit2html(text=test, output="test.html")
browseURL("test.html")
````

What is the 0% output?

Comment: I can't reproduce your output I don't' have `0%`. Which version of `data.table` are you using?

Comment: I do see it (data.table_1.8.8 and knitr_1.1). You can see it also with just `kint(text=test)` which gives `[1] "\n```r\nrequire(data.table)\nfread(\"1 2 3\\n\")\n```\n\n```\n## \r0%\r      \r\n```\n\n```\n##    V1 V2 V3\n## 1:  1  2  3\n```\n"`. The interesting part is that the `##` and `0%` end with `\r`, not `\n`. It looks like some sort of progress bar that is quickly overwritten. But `knitr` is treating the carriage returns (`\r`) as ends of lines (`\n`) and so they each get their own line.

Comment: I'm using latest versions from CRAN, data.table_1.8.8 and knitr_1.1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a % progress counter. For me it prints 0%, 5%, 10%, ... 95%, 100% (for example) with a `\r` at the end to make it appear on one line just underneath the call to `fread` when typed at the prompt.

But when called from functions, batches and knitr this is undesirable. This has now been removed. From NEWS for v1.8.9 (rev 851) :

> - % progress console meter has been removed. The ouput was inconvenient in batch mode, log files and reports which don't handle `\r`. It was too difficult to detect where `fread` is being called from, plus, removing it speeds up `fread` a little by saving code inside the C for loop (which is why it wasn't made optional instead). Use your operating system's system monitor to confirm fread is progressing. Thanks to Baptiste for highlighting :
>        [Strange output from fread when called from knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370993/strange-output-from-fread-when-called-from-knitr)

Just a quick reminder for completeness. From the top of `?fread` :

> ***This function is still under development***. For example, dates are read
>   as character (they can be converted afterwards using the excellent
>   fasttime package or standard base functions) and embedded quotes ("\""
>   and """") have problems. There are other known issues that haven't
>   been fixed and features not yet implemented. But, you may find it
>   works in many cases. Please report problems to datatable-help or Stack
>   Overflow's data.table tag.
>
> ***Not for production use yet***. Not because it's unstable in the sense
>   that it crashes or is buggy (your testing will show whether it is
>   stable in your cases or not) but because fread's arguments and
>   behaviour is likely to change in future; i.e., we expect to make
>   (hopefully minor) non-backwards-compatible changes. Why has it been
>   released to CRAN then? Because a maintenance release was asked for by
>   CRAN maintainers to comply with new stricter tests in R-devel, and a
>   few Bioconductor packages depend on data.table and Bioconductor
>   requires packages to pass R-devel checks. It was quicker to leave
>   fread in and write these paragraphs, than take fread out.

Comment: `fread` is very nice (but should praise really be given on SO?), and I honestly had no idea where this stuff was coming from (it didn't show outside of knitr) so I certainly didn't mean to upset anyone's feelings. I only wanted to find out what the cause was, to contact the relevant package's author directly.

Comment: Did you have to be so harsh in your response? I understand bristling at criticism of something you wrote, but I don't know that lashing out at the poor guy helps here. I've done this when someone went after one of my open source projects and it never turned out well.

Comment: for the record, I'm not downvoting this answer, but accepting it. I too have open source projects, spend countless hours helping people, we all know what it's like.

Comment: @baptiste -- Thanks for adding that comment. I think this really was just a big misunderstanding, and expect that Matthew will likely edit the answer when he gets back. In the meantime, I'd encourage folks to stop downvoting the answer and just let this cool off on its own. We all benefit from having Matthew and baptiste around, and I for one want them both to feel fully welcome here.

Comment: @baptiste Apologies, it was too harsh. It was the words "unpleasant noise" that I reacted to.

Answer (score 12):

It isn't a problem to be reported.

As stated by Matthew Dowle, this is a progress counter from `fread`

You can  set `results = 'hide'` to avoid these results being included

````
library(knitr)

test = "```{r, results = 'hide'}
require(data.table) 
fread('1 2 3\n')
```"
knit2html(text=test, output="test.html")
browseURL("test.html")
````

Look, no progress bar.

---

At a practical level, I think it would be sensible to have `results = 'hide'` or even `include = FALSE` for a step like this.

You will not want to repeat this kind of reading in step, practically, you only ever want to read the data in once, then you would serialize it (using `save`, `saveRDS` or similar), so you could use that next time (which would be faster).

---

Edit in light of the comment

I would split the processing up into a number of smaller chunks. You could then not include the reading in chunk, but include a dummy version that is not evaluated (so you can see the code, but not include the results)

````
```{r libraries}
require(data.table) 
 ```

```{r loaddata, include = FALSE}
DT <- fread('yourfile')
```

```{r loaddummy, ref.label = 'loaddata', eval = FALSE, echo = TRUE}
```

```{r dostuff}
# doing other stuff
```
````

Comment: thanks, but since I want to see other results from the same chunk that leaves me with the workaround I found earlier (redirecting the fread line to sink).

Comment: @baptiste. I would split the chunk up. You don't want to repeatedly read the file in, so have it as a separate chunk that is cached, so you only do it once.

Comment: thanks @mnel. The question was more to find out about the _underlying cause_ to report it; I'm familiar with the options in knitr to overcome the issue, use cache, etc.

Comment: @baptiste -- no worries. It is updated every 1e5 rows. (looking at `fread.c`, perhaps    `if (i%10000==0 && clock()>nexttime)` could be `if (verbose && i%10000==0 && clock()>nexttime)` -- The reason you may not have seen it is that you haven't sat and watched the console while running `fread` (it disappears afterwards)`

Answer (score 1):

There is a parameter called `showProgress` in `fread`, if you set it to `FALSE`, then you will not see the progress output. (It's useful in making r markdown.)